failure: Build failed with an exception

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\K.VARSHITH REDDY\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio3\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\K.VARSHITH REDDY.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\K.VARSHITH REDDY.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
clear cache and restarted it but got same error
gradlew.bat : The term 'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

gradlew.bat

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gradlew.bat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException



